How could I get person's IP that connected to me with UDP?
I'm using zrok and playit (testing which is better and secured) services to host my UDP server for my game where I want to play with my community. And when I try to find way to get person's IP who is connecting (to IP-Ban users), I receive 127.0.0.1:someport. I were trying to make UDP receiver, get client game data to check if everything is fine (and it's not midified one) and resend it to my game server to control traffic but as I said before I got local ip and no game data.
I were trying to search in docs how could I get person's IP but unfortunately my brain couldn't handle it all.
And I would like to ask what could I use instead, if I can't get IP from these services, what service I could use for that. Because zrok has admin panel and overview command in that that shows other connected users to account which I use to connect to private udpTunnel (I'd like to use service which is free and secured from D/DOS because I can't host it on my ip, I were testing DDOS on me and it crashing my internet)
